# Создание treeview в pyside2

Tags: python, treeview, pyside2

Пытаюсь создать окно для отображение дерикторий, в которой в дальнейшем юзер будет сохранять файлы. Просто отображать папки.

код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1266, 798)
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(Form)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 611, 241))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        #-------------
        self.treeView.QFileSystemModel.directoryLoaded('D:\test\qt')
        #-------------
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 70, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 42, 541, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "TextLabel", None, -1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
   ui = Ui_Form()
   ui.setupUi(Form)
   Form.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат должен быть следующим, окно в которм юзер булет выбирать папку и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в моем примере заменить `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` на `from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` и установить свой путь `D:/test/qt` .

```
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import os

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1266, 798)
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(Form)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 611, 241))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        #-------------
# ?        self.treeView.QFileSystemModel.directoryLoaded('D:\test\qt')
        #-------------
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 70, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 42, 541, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "TextLabel", None, -1))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.resize(600, 400)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()

        # Установите фильтры, для модели каталога. (какие вам нужны)
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Hidden | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)

        self.path = os.path.expanduser('D:/_Qt')                          # <-- ('D:/test/qt')
        self.parentIndex  = self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))

        # void QFileSystemModel::directoryLoaded(const QString &path)
        # Этот сигнал испускается, когда поток завершил загрузку пути.
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)


    def _loaded(self, path):
        print('_loaded', self.path) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#   Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#   ui = Ui_Form()
#   ui.setupUi(Form)
#   Form.show()
   w = Widget()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: огромное спасибо. вы сразу решили как минимум 2 мои проблемы... это создание более одного класса и использование лицензированного ПО.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что для использования в коммерческих целях PyQT5  необходимо покупать лицензию ?

Comment: @WilteRatenau  https://toster.ru/q/584331

Comment: ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @WilteRatenau Если мой ответ помог вам, не забудьте отметить его как полезный.

Comment: правда не совсем понимаю , теперь class widget является основным при запуске ? 
и почему меняется размер treeview, даже пробовал установить sizePolicy но это не помогло. 
могли бы вы привести пример, как правильно разделять классы и подклассы

Comment: @WilteRatenau попробуйте так `self.treeView.setFixedSize(400, 400)` или так `sp = self.treeView.sizePolicy()
sp.setHorizontalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
sp.setVerticalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
self.treeView.setSizePolicy(sp)`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94326/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-s-nick).